# Retrieve data from ParseUser after using FindAsync

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, ienumerable, facebook-unity-sdk

I've created a number of users in Parse. There're Facebook users and non-Facebook user. For each Facebook user I've saved an extra column of "facebookID".

Now I'd like to get all the ParseUsers that are Facebook Users. So I applied a Task to query the users with "facebookID" in them.

```
var Task = ParseUser.Query.WhereExists("facebookID").FindAsync().ContinueWith(t=>{

        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.Log ("t.Exception=" + t.Exception);
            //cannot load friendlist
            return;
        }
        else{
            fbFriends = t.Result;

            foreach(var result in fbFriends){
                string id = (string)result["facebookID"];

                //facebookUserIDList is a List<string>
                facebookUserIDList.Add(id);
            }

            return;
        }
    });
```

The above code works perfectly. However, I'd like to get more data from each Facebook User, for example, the `current_coins` that the user has. So I change the foreach loop to:

```
foreach(var result in fbFriends){
    string id = (string)result["facebookID"];
    int coins = (int)result["current_coins"];
    //facebookUserIDList is a List<string>
    facebookUserIDList.Add(id);
}
```

I've changed the facebookUserIDList into a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` instead of a `List<string>` in order to save the other data as well. But the foreach loop does not run at all. Does it mean I can only get the `facebookID` from it because I specified `WhereExists("facebookID")` in `FindAsync()`? Can anybody explain it to me please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should contain all Parse primitive data type(such as Boolean, Number, String, Date...) for each Object. but not Pointers nor Relation.

for Pointers, you can explicitly include them in the result using the "Include" method

for any ParseRelation you have to requery them

Comment: You're right. I didn't know the "Number" data type was Int64 instead of Int32. So it cannot be converted to int directly with the way I did above. Thanks!